# Descent: Can you get rid of cursed items?

Tags: descent

In Descent there are various cursed items, which we always played as bind on pickup?

Is this the case?  Can you wield any other weapon while you have a cursed item?  How do you work around this completely making useless a character that gets an item it can't use well (a mage with a two handed sword).

Answer (score 3):

I don't recall there being any rules for auto-equipping cursed items; you can elect to use it if you want to, but you don't have to.

You get a curse token for equipping a cursed item, and while you can remove the cursed item as normal, you do not lose the curse token for un-equipping the item (so if you re-equip it later, you get another curse token).

In your example, if the mage can simply choose not to equip the weapon.

Now, **Dark Relics**, on the other hand, must be equipped when found, and the only normal way to remove them is to die.  Fun fun...

Comment: This is correct; you never *have* to use a cursed item.  The point is that the cursed items are generally significantly better than non-cursed items in the same deck; several are well worth the risk in the right circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

You can drop them at any time or sell them when you are at a the market.

The curse applies when they are equipped and the curse can be removed by dying or by buying the voodoo doll for 200 gold in the store.  It came with one of the expansions and removes 3 status marks, which includes the curse marker.